# R - modify an unknown function

Tags: r, function

I have a function f of some vector **x**
The function in R is written as :
 `f <- function(x){#insert some function of x here}`
I would like to return (-f), which denotes the negative of the function. In the case the function itself is known beforehand, this is a simple exercise.
However, in this case, I don't know what this function is

Could someone please help me with the R code to carry this out? (The output needs to be a function in the vector x.)

An example would be - f(x) = x + 1, then -f(x) = -x - 1

Thank you!

Comment: According to your example, `-1 * f(x)` should work...could you be more specific ? Do you *always* want to return the negative, do you need to handle special cases ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following function `getNegFn()` takes a function `fn` and returns a function which returns the negative return value of `fn`:

```
getNegFn <- function(fn){
    fnOut <- function(){
        - do.call(what=fn, args=as.list(match.call())[-1])
    }
    formals(fnOut) <- formals(fn)
    fnOut
}
```

An example:

```
fn <- function(x) x + 1
nFn <- getNegFn(fn=fn)

fn(1)
[1] 2
nFn(1)
[1] -2
```

Also works if the input function has `...` arguments:

```
fn2 <- function(x, ...) x + sum(unlist(list(...)))
nFn2 <- getNegFn(fn=fn2)

fn2(x=1, y=2)
[1] 3
nFn2(x=1, y=2)
[1] -3
```

Comment: thank you very much! This is precisely what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

Look into do.call(). You can give it a string of a function's name as an arguement, and that function will then be called with the arguments you provide (in a `list()`), so, for example, you can do:

```
funcname<-"mean" 
dat<-1:5
do.call(funcname, list(dat))*(-1)
```

Would run as if you called `mean(dat)*(-1)`, which will give you:

```
[1] -3
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply; the answer below was what I needed - it was the do.call function I needed to review!